# How to delete a git head but not a tag having the same name

Tags: git, tags, branch

I have a branch and tag having the same name abc as follows:

```
> git show-ref abc
c7f57ba70d1ee9624df2d288f9934d1f086dc4e5 refs/heads/abc
d23de1ba0faed701fd64ccd53c0aa03455f6edd6 refs/tags/abc
```

Now I want to delete the heads *abc* and want to retain the tags *abc*. How can I do that? Will the following delete only the heads *abc* keeping the tags *abc* as it is:

```
> git branch -D refs/heads/abc
```

Please note I cannot afford to delete the tags *abc*. So what command can I run ?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can execute the branch command you propose, you won't delete the same-name tag.

The branch command doesn't delete tags, you'd have to explicitly delete it with `git tag -d abc` if you wanted to.

You can just test it in a tiny test repo if my word isn't enough to reassure you.

```
$ git init testrepo
Initialized empty Git repository in <somepath>/testrepo/.git/

$ cd testrepo

$ echo "test" > test.txt

$ git commit -am "First commit"
[master (root-commit) 80f9162] First commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt

$ git branch myref

$ git tag myref

$ git branch
* master
  myref

$ git tag -l
myref

$ git branch -D myref
Deleted branch myref (was 80f9162).

$ git branch
* master

$ git tag -l
myref
```

As a sidenote, branches you feed to the `git branch` command are expected in their short form (`abc`), not the complete path (`refs/heads/abc`)